# What is the scope of @EnableTransactionManagement?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-transactions

I'm trying to understand where is the right place to put `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation in case of multiple JavaConfig contexts?

Consider following scenario: I have JPA config in JPAConfig.java and AppConfig.java with set of service beans. Then I compose overall application config in RootConfig.java.

I define transaction manager within JPAConfig.java as well as enable scanning for JPA repositories - as those expose transactional behavior, I put `@EnableTransactionManagement` over JPAConfig and it works.

However, some of service beans also need to have transactional methods e.g. accessing several repositories within single transaction. Should I also put `@EnableTransactionManagement` over AppConfig as well? Looking into implementation of this annotation is seems to me that such approach would cause redefinition of some beans. And actually doing so doesn't seem to work for me.

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.mypackage.repositories")
public class JPAConfig {
 // ... here are EntityManager and PlatformTransactionManager beans
}


@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.mypackage.services")
// @EnableTransactionManagement // - ???
public class AppConfig {
}

@Configuration
@Import({AppConfig.class, JPAConfig.class})
public class RootConfig {
}
```

Appreciate any advices.

Comment: That annotation adds transaction management stuff to the whole application context. That's its scope.

Comment: But it does not seem to enable transaction annotations processing for overall RootConfig. At least, it does not work for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After some experiments I seem to have found the answer myself:

- There is no need to configure `@EnableTransactionManagement` on each
  piece of context configuration although it does matter how early this
  annotation is discovered as it registers `internalTransactionAdvisor`
  which actually processes `@Transactional` annotations on created beans.
- In my case, I changed the order of contexts in `@Import` declaration so
  that `PersistenceConfig` that holds `@EnableTransactionManagement` is the
  first. After this beans from other pieces can use AOP declarative
  transaction.
- Another caveat relates to simultaneous use of `@EnableTransactionManagement` and `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity`. Global method security uses bean post processing which seems to require whole security configuration to be wired. BeanPostProcessors are created early on context start-up so you can't use declarative `@Transactional` in any bean that would be needed to bootstrap spring security (in my case `UserDetailsContextMapper`) - advisor is not yet created then!

Comment: How did you manage to get Transactions with your spring-security configuration?

Comment: It's been a while now :) As far as I remember, I just ended up with a programmatic transaction. It was really single place when it was needed so such solution suited me well.