# @EnableTransactionManagement not working when in RootConfig

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-transactions

I have a problem with my Spring (4.3.9-RELEASE) configuration.

I have a WebMVC application running and everything works nice with my current configuration.

I will omit a lot which I consider unimportant due to the overall complexity of the complication. Please let me know if you're missing something important.

```
@WebServlet 
@PropertySource("classpath:myAppConf.properties")
public class ServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
                return new Class[] {MainAppConfig.class } ;
        }

        @Override
        protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
                return new Class[] {WebAppConfig.class };
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] getServletMappings() {
                return new String[] { "/" };
        }

        @Override
        protected String getServletName() {
                return "myServletFooBar";
        }

}
```

*MainAppConfig:*

```
@Configuration
@Import({HibernateConfig.class})
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "my.app.security"})
public class MainAppConfig {
    ...
}
```

*WebAppConfig:*

```
@EnableWebMvc()
@Configuration()
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "my.app.controller" })
@Import({ServiceConfig.class})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class WebAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{
    ...
}
```

I have all my Controllers and Services (annotated with `@Transactional`) in my `WebAppConfiguration` (which is annotated with `@EnableTransactionManagement`). My Hibernate configurations (transaction manager, data source etc.) are in my `MainAppConfiguration`.

Transactions are working fine with this configuration.

Now I needed to have transactions in my `MainAppConfiguration`-Context (for a customized Spring-Security AuthenticationProvider (extends from `DaoAuthenticationProvider`).

This does not work because `@EnableTransactionManagement` is on my `WebAppConfig`. When trying to run a Transaction from my custom Authentication provider I get the following error.

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread
```

So I tried to move all my Services to my `MainAppConfig` (also the `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation) but then I get the same message in my Controlloer Methods, which are calling the services.

I Also tried to move the `@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)` and `@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "my.app.security"})` annotations from my MainAppConfig to my WebAppConfig (which makes more sense in my opinion). But then Spring-Security complains, that there is `No bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' available`

**Where is the flaw in my configuration?**

Comment: The flaw is that your configuration is spread and things are being loaded twice due to component-scanning.

Comment: I can't see anything loaded twice here (can you point me where you think something is loaded twice?)

I'm also not happy with having RootConfig and WebAppConfig spread, but putting everything into WebAppConfig simply doesn't work (see my `SpringSecurityFilterChain` error described above).

Comment: You are component-scanning stuff (not sure which package the `ServiceConfig` is in and what that scans) ... Also `@webServlet` and `@PropertySource` on the `ServletInitializer` don't really make sense.

Comment: The Component -Scan on my `my.app.security`-package loads basically my security config (Annotated with `@EnableWebSecurity`). 

In my package are all my classes annotated with `@Controller`

All My services which are annotated with `@Transactional` are defined in my class `WebAppConfig` with `@Bean` annotations.

So I'm pretty sure, that there is nothing loaded twice. The application is pretty big and runs for multiple years in production. I simply never used Transactions from within my RootContext. But now I would need it...

Comment: Your services should be the transactional boundary, not the controllers. So basically if you adhere to that the only thing you would need to do is move the `@Import` and `@EnableTransactionManagement` to `MainAppConfig`. If that doesn't work you have services in places that get picked up by the component scanning in the wrong place (or you are doing things in a really strange way).

Comment: Thanks for your effort: As mentioned above: I tried to move all my services (annotated with `@Transactional`) to the RootConfig. My Controllers are not annotated with `@Transactional`, but they use those services. 

After moving my services to my RootConfig I got the exception `Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread` when calling one of the `@Autowired` Services within my controllers.

Comment: You must also move the `@EnableTransactionManagement` and as stated if that doesn't work you have a component scan somewhere detecting the service for the web context instead of the root context.

Comment: Of course I moved `@EnableTransactionManagement` after moving my services. I will try it again and double check if the services are really Instantiated twice by spring. Maybe I have overlooked here something. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Should I also move my @Controller-Classes into the RootConfig?

Comment: That isn't necessary.

Comment: I moved all my services to my Root-Config (`MainAppConfig`) again. Services are loaded only once (put a breakpoint in the service-constructor to check). I moved the `@EnableTransactionManagement` annotation to my `MainAppConfig`. When calling a service-method (e.g. from my custom AuthenticationProvider where @Autowired my service) I can see, that the service is proxied by Spring, but still transactions won't work here. (same error: `Could not obtain transaction-synchronized Session for current thread`). I really don't get it, why transactions don't work in my MainAppConfig (but in WebAppConfig

Comment: It turned out, that it matters at which `@Configuration`-File the `@EnableTransactionManagement` is added. I had to put it on the file which contained all my Services (see answer below). I didn't expect that.

Funny thing is, that this is not necesarry when adding the `@EnableTransactionManagement` to my WebAppConfig. (I also included my services there from another configuration.

However, it works now! Thanks for your help @M. Deinum

Comment: It shouldn't matter which file it is on, as everything is put into a single context.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately it matters. I don't know why and I'm not happy about that. But it works now.

Comment: Then there must be something weird in your configuration. Everything is in a single context and where the `@Enable*` annotations are shouldn't matter as long as they are in the same context. Also (judging from your answer) your `ServiceConfig` isn't a `@COnfiguration` which makes it behave differently as a regular configuration bean.

Comment: My `ServiceConfig` is a configuration-class and I'm including it from within my `MainAppConfig` with an `@Import` statement (to be more specific by using a custom Class which implements `ImportSelector` and `EnvironmentAware`) Don't ask me why transactions only work when my `ServiceConfig` is annotated with `@EnableTransactionManagement` but not when my `MainAppConfig` is annotated with it. Look at the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26087522/1219104 . This guy had a similar problem. Maybe it's a flaw in Spring?

BTW: The discussion is very appreciated!

Comment: We use a similar setup and it doesn't matter where the annotation goes. One thing I can think of is that due to some AOP (maybe security) one of the configuration classes gets a double proxy which makes the annotations unreadable.

Comment: Mhm... I will check if there is a double-proxy for one of my configuration classes. DO you think I can also check this by setting a breakpoint in the configuration-class' constructor?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution which works for me thanks to the hints of @M. Deinum :

I moved all my Services to the RootContext (`MainAppConfig.class` in my case). But not directly, I imported another Configuration which contained all my Service-Beans:

```
@Import(ServiceConfig.class)
public class MainAppConfig {
   ...
}
```

Within my `ServiceConfig.class` I had all my Service-`@Bean`-Definitions.
It's important, that the `ServiceConfig` is annotated with the `@EnableTransactionManagement`. If you put it on the `MainConfig`-Class transactions won't work.

```
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ServiceConfig {
     @Bean(name="userService")
     UserService userService() {
         return new UserServiceImpl();      
     }
     ...
}
```